# How to set CRTL+F1 to execute sp_help on the item currently selected

Tags: t-sql, ide

I worked at a place that had this set up.  It was nice.  Highlight a table name and click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, and exec sp_help [this_object] was executed.  How can I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SSMS menu select `Tools -> Options` then the Keyboard tab.

By default `sp_help` is already mapped to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Yay!  I guess my memory failed me by one modifier key.